# Load current for LM317

Tags: current-source, linear-regulator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbOzeG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[LM317](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM317-D.PDF) requires 10mA load to maintain regulation. the simplest option is to add a resistor, with a 10 ohm resistor as a load I get 16mA at the output. I know heat is going to be a problem and it's not going to work.

The other option is to use [TL431](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TL431-D.PDF):

[image]

The problem is what happens if the input `V+` get near 0V? is it going to stop drawing current because there's no voltage to operate?

I want to have an steady 10mA load for LM317 as datasheet suggested, but because it's a voltage regulator and the output of LM317 can go to 0V I don't know how to do it, need guidance please.

Comment: I do not understand the circuit with the opamp. The opamp will force the output of the circuit to 0 V so there will be no voltage across the load resistor so no current will flow. *I know heat is going to be a problem* Why? At 10 mA power dissipation (and resulting heat) isn't much of an issue. Worst case you get 24 V * 10 mA = 240 mW, the LM317 can easily dissipate that without a heatsink. I dare to say that you cannot explain how this circuit is supposed to work. I have seen (and designed) current sources, none of then are similar to your LM317 circuit.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie it's not going to absolute 0V, I want the output to get to 0V. there's no other option other than a resistor?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I think it's simple enough for me to explain that opamp compares two inputs and set the output accordingly so LM317 can have an steady output, constant voltage. Instead of daring me kindly please guide me, give the keywords to google or schematics to analyze.

Comment: *it's not going to absolute 0V* It is, my proof: the feedback loop opamp => LM317 => - input of opamp. The + input of the opamp is at 0 V so assuming the opamp can work with that, the - input will (through the LM317) be at 0 V also. Now **prove me wrong**. I'm not going to discuss a circuit that **cannot work** (but feel to prove me wrong if you can). If you post a circuit that cannot work, you will be challenged.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie it's on breadboard right now! output will get lower only if i change the resistor to a lower value. can you please explain why it can not work? what are the downsides? I think it was you who suggested to me in an earlier question to learn how to use opamp and feedback circuit...

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie *"I have seen (and designed) current sources"* BTW it's not a current source but a simple voltage regulator...

Comment: Where does your firgure of 16mA come from? It's not 0V/ 10 ohms. It seems to be on a node, like a voltage would be, rather than through a component or wire, like a current would be. The opamp will pull the 317 adj pin down to -1.2v (or whatever is needed as there's no load on the 317, what with its zero volt output not sending a current through the load) to maintain both its inputs at the same 0V, which means the output voltage will be zero. What the actual purpose of your circuit? Why have you illustrated one voltage source, and one current source, as if they're alternatives?

Comment: I have to agree with previous comments, I can not figure out what you are trying to do or what your schematics are supposed to mean.

Comment: Connect the 10 mA load between OUT and ADJ. There's a 1.25 V drop there so 125 ohms. Note that your op-amp must be capable of sinking 10 mA.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking.  What's the goal of your circuit?

Comment: @TimWescott to regulate voltage digitally but LM317 needs 10mA load in order to be able to regulate, the question is how can I maintain that constant 10mA when the voltage at the output of LM317 is 0V. I don't know how else I can explain the problem.

Comment: voltage reference -> DAC -> power amplifier.  Done.

Comment: @TimWescott I'm sorry but I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: Drive a DAC, which operates from a good voltage reference, from your processor.  Feed the output of the DAC to a precision power amplifier.

Comment: @TimWescott I still don't get it, There's a DAC already connected to the non-inverting input of opamp. can you post an answer with more explanation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have -5V available in your circuit. Use a load resistor, or constant-current circuit, with its lower voltage connected to -5V instead of ground. For example, 500\$\Omega\$ from the output to -5V will draw 10mA even when the output is 0V.

Comment: Thanks, What if we didn't have that -5V?

Comment: I don't know...if you don't have -5V then what do you have? Don't make us guess.

Comment: I connected a 500 ohm resistor between output and -5V, it's regulating well but it doesn't go all the way to 0V. minimum is around 2.3V. should I ask that in a separate question?

Comment: Yes, and describe the voltages at all of the pins of the op amp.